# Making DIVs act like a table using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Alright, while designing a site, I came across a thought... I have a few parts of my site which would be better suited acting as a table, but isn't tabular data. For some reason it really bugs me to use a table for something that isn't a table. So I noted CSS's display options, yet I can't get it to work right. Here is what I am trying. What is the issue?

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
    <div class="td">Row 1, Cell 2</div>
    <div class="td">Row 1, Cell 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
    <div class="td">Row 2, Cell 2</div>
    <div class="td">Row 2, Cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the CSS looks like.

```
div.table {border: 1px solid black; display: table; }
div.tr {border: 1px solid black; display: table-row; }
div.td {border: 1px solid black; display: table-cell; }
```

I would like the page to look like a table was used but the 'cells' all go on a new-line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Works great in Firefox 3.6.12.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: looks like table data to me. Please do not reinvent the wheel with divs and css class names that mirror table markup

Comment: @redsquare- Reinventing the wheel is my specialty.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Strange: What you quote looks fine, and should work. Are you sure there is no overriding `display: block !important` somewhere?

But as my opinion, I'm going to say that for the love of God, just use a table. :)

Seriously. The main argument for not using tables in such situations is that they aren't the right element semantically. But looking at that div-soup, you have to admit a `<table>` is the way more preferable construct, even if it's not *exactly* tabular data you're displaying.

Comment: I totally agree. After all, I used to use tables for design. However, with the complications that came with tables, I switched to DIVs.

I simply don't like using tables incorrectly out of pride and a desire to use /correct?/ documentation.

Ah... It seems that I was emulating the page in IE6... Works fine.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu I see your point and it's generally a good philosophy to work with, but in this case, the markup required to do it in pure CSS looks worse and is harder to read than a `table` IMO, so I would tend to make an exception (also because a native table element works in IE6, while `display-*` does not)

Comment: Point taken. At this point, I think I will agree, and use a table. Small Note: My Websites don't support IE6. Not vice versa.

Comment: I have to switch to div because the contenteditable attribute doesn't work with table/td in Edge.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old post, but since nobody actually fixed your problem with the DIV's I thought I'd give it a go.

Your problem is simple...your cell elements are divs and therefore are display: block, use spans instead for table cells (or add display:inline to the .cell CSS).

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <span class="td">Row 1, Cell 1</span>
    <span class="td">Row 1, Cell 2</span>
    <span class="td">Row 1, Cell 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <span class="td">Row 2, Cell 1</span>
    <span class="td">Row 2, Cell 2</span>
    <span class="td">Row 2, Cell 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The divs for the .td class are not display:block, nor will your spans with the .td class applied be display:inline, because the author is already setting the .td class to display:table-cell

Answer (score 9):

```
<body>
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How is this different from the original code snippet (except that it uses `style="..."` instead of `class` and CSS)?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a browser issue? Your code works for me in Chrome. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/xVTkP/

What are you using?

(but seriously, as others of said, use a table)

Comment: Yeah, I was emulating it using IE6. Forgot to switch it to Firefox... :/

Answer (score 4):

What browser are you using? These values [aren't implemented perfectly](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) in all browsers. Still, **what's the point** of trying to emulate tables with divs+CSS? Why not just use a table?

HTML creators generally avoid using tables for data which isn't tabular because of the early (somewhere in the last 10 years? can't remember) backlash that resulted from *overuse* of tables as layout elements. Think: nested tables in nested tables, empty cells just for padding, etc. **Get over it**. Use the element that gets the job done.

Personally, I think that `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, etc. should have been left out of the CSS `display` spec.